# How to check username & password for custom login

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class student(models.Model):

  u_email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  u_username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  u_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

view.py

```
def login_check(request, *args,**kwargs ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_username= request.POST['username']
        c_password = request.POST['password']
        print(username,password)
```

how can i perform following query for authenticate student in django

`"SELECT id FROM student WHERE u_username = c_username  and password = c_password"`

Comment: "SELECT id FROM student WHERE u_username = c_username and u_password = c_password"

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text in your database!

Comment: I'll go stronger. You **must not** do this. Use the built in authentication framework, which takes care of having your passwords correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) and add this to your code:

```
students = student.objects.filter(u_username=c_username, u_password=c_password)
if students.exists():
    # do whatever you like with list students .e.g: 
    # access to first one id with students[0].id
```

don't remember to add import statement in the view

```
from models import student

def login_check(request, *args,**kwargs ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_username= request.POST['username']
        c_password = request.POST['password']
        students = student.objects.filter(u_username=c_username, u_password=c_password)
        if students:
            print(students[0].id)
            # ...
```

**NOTE**: Please don't save your passwords as plain text. use hash functions and save their output instead (see [this](http://sha1-hash-online.waraxe.us/)). you never need to know the user's password. You just want to verify an incoming user knows the password for an account.

Comment: Thank you so much :)  for answer my question

Comment: You don't need `.exists()` -- `if students:` is sufficient.  ps: don't encourage the storing of passwords in plain text (and pps: how do you know the first student is the correct one..?)

Comment: @thebjorn. thanks for your suggestion. I updated my answer.

Comment: @KaushalGajjar please accept my answer if it is work